# MySQL "Unexpected token" error while updating

Tags: mysql

I am running this query to update a password field on user with email x@mail.com  and want to update his password, but I am having error.
The mysql query:

```
UPDATE users
SET password=myword
WHERE email=x@mail.com;
```

The password field is an md5 encrypted field.

The error I got is

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'myword' in 'field list'
```

This is my table structure:
[the mysql table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hahvP.jpg)

I tried to put the values in "" and '' as well as `` but still the error occurs.

Comment: No @David because I used quotes when above syntax did not work. Please check the error I provided. I appreciate your time anyways.

Comment: The code shown in the question is (was) using double-quotes, which is incorrect.  Now the code shown is using no quotes, which is also incorrect.  String literals in SQL are single-quoted.  You may indeed be *claiming* that you've tried that, but the ongoing edits to the question do not demonstrate this.  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Firstly I tried everything without quoting, then single quoting, then double quoting. Anyways, thanks, and I am getting the code to sql fiddle and will share a link here. Sorry for troubling you, @David, I would get back here soon. Thanks for being there.

Comment: FYI: `md5` (and other hashing methods like `sha1`, etc...) are not suited to store passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You must use single quotes for string values.

```sql
UPDATE users
SET password='myword'
WHERE email='x@mail.com';
```

Double quotes are used for quoting table and column names with special characters and the like.

Comment: But it doesn't solve the error. Phpmyadmin still throwing same error. I tried quotes when nothing worked. However I appreciate your answer, but the above solution isnt executing in phpmyadmin.

Comment: It works just fine for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gMyuyauYZJmm83oFBYWKr2/0